# Making changes with Selenium in a web page and the response of the driver returns the same value (Scrapy, Python)

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, driver, response

In a web page that has the Show More button, I click it in a loop till it isnt around anymore (I can see the entire page). Now I need to get some data but the data that I'm getting is the same as before clicking the Show More button.

This is the code that does this:

```
    bodyBefore = response.xpath('/body').get()

    # Click the Show More button till it isn't anymore
    showmore_btn = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
        "//a[@class='event__more event__more--static']")

    while len(showmore_btn) > 0:
        showmore_btn[0].send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        # Add more time if the previous command doens`t work (Bad internet connection)
        time.sleep(5)
        showmore_btn = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
            "//a[@class='event__more event__more--static']")

    bodyAfter = response.xpath('/body').get()
```

I can't get the new html code in order to scrape it. (With bodyBefore and bodyAfter I can prove this easily)

Does someone know how to do this?

The url I'm scraping is:
https://www.flashscore.com/football/england/premier-league-2018-2019/results/

In this case I want to scrape each match url that appears after clicking on Show More

Comment: show page url, probably you need to make driver to go to frame where data are displayed.

Comment: I tried that already and it doesn't work

Comment: I checked with Selenium, you should replace the xpath path with find_element_by_xpath ('// * [@ id = "live-table"] / div [1] / div / div') and you can use .get_attribute (' innerHTML ') to export the data to an html file as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to find main table then all `<div>` tags that contains rows of data.
Next you can loop over elements in row to get text data. I added progress string to loop, hope you enjoy it :)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os
import time
import sys


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path =os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()) + "/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.flashscore.com/football/england/premier-league-2018-2019/results/")

# extend table
show_more_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='event__more event__more--static']")
while len(show_more_buttons) > 0:
    show_more_buttons[0].send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(2)
    show_more_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='event__more event__more--static']")

# get table and events
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="live-table"]/div[1]/div/div')
events = table.find_elements_by_class_name('event__match.event__match--static.event__match--oneLine')

# loop over events and collect data
count = 1
data = []
for item in events:
    time = item.find_element_by_class_name('event__time').text
    participant_home = item.find_element_by_class_name('event__participant.event__participant--home').text
    event_scores = item.find_element_by_class_name('event__scores.fontBold').text
    participant_away = item.find_element_by_class_name('event__participant.event__participant--away').text
    event_part = item.find_element_by_class_name('event__part').text
    data.append([time, participant_home, event_scores.replace('\n', ''), participant_away, event_part])
    sys.stdout.write('\r')
    sys.stdout.write("progress: %.2f %%" % ((count/len(events))*100))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    count += 1

for item in data:
    print(item)
```

**Output:**

```
['12.05. 16:00', 'Brighton', '1 - 4', 'Manchester City', '(1 - 2)']
['12.05. 16:00', 'Burnley', '1 - 3', 'Arsenal', '(0 - 0)']
..
..
..
['11.08. 16:00', 'Watford', '2 - 0', 'Brighton', '(1 - 0)']
['11.08. 13:30', 'Newcastle', '1 - 2', 'Tottenham', '(1 - 2)']
['10.08. 21:00', 'Manchester Utd', '2 - 1', 'Leicester', '(1 - 0)']
```

Comment: Thanks! Now it works perfectly. My mistake was that I was getting the data from the response, not from the driver.